# deriving cdf of uniform distribution

Tags: probability

I have that the pdf for a uniform distribution is given by $$f(x) = \frac{1}{b-a}$$ if $a \leq x \leq b $ and $0$ otherwise.

I am trying to derive the cdf.

From definition I have that the cdf is given by $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \ dt$

So I will split it up to 3 intervals:

If $x < a$ we have that $f(x) = 0$ so $F(x) = 0$ here.

If $ a \leq x \leq b $ we have that $$F(x) = \int_{a}^x f(t) \ dt = \frac{x-a}{b-a}$$

If $ x > b$ the pdf says that $f(x) = 0$ here, so surely the cdf would be $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 0 \ dt = 0 $$ but however it is equal to $1$.

What is wrong with my approach, and how would you usually derive these answers.

Comment: Good formatting and +1 for showing your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything up to $x > b$ is perfect.

But your reasoning in the final case is not quite correct, because the integral is taken over an interval that **includes** parts of the PDF that are nonzero.  In other words, the interval $(a,b)$ is a subset of the interval $(-\infty, x)$ if $x > b$.  Just because the density is zero when $x > b$, it doesn't mean that the integral from $(-\infty, x)$ is itself zero, because as we can see, there are points within the interval of integration for which the density is positive.

For example, if I say to you to calculate the integral of $g(x) = 1-x$ from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$, what would you write?  $$\int_{x=0}^1 1-x \, dx = \left[x - \frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{x=0}^1 = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.$$  Now if I give you the function $$h(x) = \begin{cases} g(x), & 0 \le x \le 1 \\ 0, & x > 1, \end{cases},$$ what would the integral of $h$ be from $x = 0$ to $x = 2$?  It's the same as the above, because the area under the curve of $h$ from $x = 1$ to $x = 2$ is zero, so you've not added any area, but the total area is not zero because you still had area from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$.

Comment: Ah of course thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If $x>b$:
$$
F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^af(t)\;dt+\int_a^b f(t)\;dt+\int_b^xf(t)\;dt
$$
The first integral is $0$, the second $1$ and the third $0$.